# Spring form checkboxes - Putting each 2 checkboxes in one row

Tags: html, spring, jsp, checkbox, css-tables

I've been trying to put each 2 Spring Form checkboxes in a separate table row using bootstrap but I couldn't.
Here's my code:

```
<f:form action="/saveEvent" modelAttribute="event" method="post" id="eventForm">

...

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Trainers</label><br>
            <f:checkboxes path="trainers" items="${trainersList}" 
                          element="div class='col-md-6 checkbox form-control' 
                          CssStyle='float:right'"
                          itemLabel="fullName" itemValue="id" delimiter=""/>
        </div>
</f:form>
```

And this is the result I am getting

[image: Current result screenshot]

And here's the generated HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Trainers</label><br>
    <div class="col-md-6 checkbox form-control" cssstyle="float:right">
    <input id="trainers1" name="trainers" type="checkbox" value="6" checked="checked">
    <label for="trainers1">Walid Mbarek</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 checkbox form-control" cssstyle="float:right">
    <input id="trainers2" name="trainers" type="checkbox" value="7" checked="checked">
    <label for="trainers2">Bouraoui Chebili</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 checkbox form-control" cssstyle="float:right">
    <input id="trainers3" name="trainers" type="checkbox" value="14">
    <label for="trainers3">Randy Ross</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 checkbox form-control" cssstyle="float:right">
    <input id="trainers4" name="trainers" type="checkbox" value="17">
    <label for="trainers4">Mohamed Ali Thaier</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 checkbox form-control" cssstyle="float:right">
    <input id="trainers5" name="trainers" type="checkbox" value="21" checked="checked">
    <label for="trainers5">Echrak Saidani</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 checkbox form-control" cssstyle="float:right">
    <input id="trainers6" name="trainers" type="checkbox" value="25">
    <label for="trainers6">Marwen Chatti</label>
  </div><input type="hidden" name="_trainers" value="on"> </div>
```

I really like the way they look now, but the way I need them to display is a pair per row.

I also need the result to be in a table because I will have a search filter based on js that works only with tables

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution which is splitting the items list `${trainersList}` into two lists in the controller and passing them as separate attributes.
The code in the controller was

`model.addAttribute("trainersList",trainersList);`

Now it's become

`model.addAttribute("trainersList1",trainersList.subList(0,(int)(trainersList.size()/2 +1)));
model.addAttribute("trainersList2",trainersList.subList((int)(trainersList.size()/2 +1),trainersList.size()));`

And in the JSP page I changed the code to

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Trainers</label><br>
  <div class="col-md-6"style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:6px;">
    <f:checkboxes path="trainers" items="${trainersList1}"
                  element="div class='col-md-6 checkbox form-control' 
                  style='padding-left:6px;'"
                  itemLabel="fullName" itemValue="id" delimiter=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6"style="padding-left:6px;padding-right:0px;">
    <f:checkboxes path="trainers" items="${trainersList2}"
                  element="div class='col-md-6 checkbox form-control' 
                  style='padding-right:6px;'"
                  itemLabel="fullName" itemValue="id" delimiter=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Current Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkqVq.jpg)

I don't feel like this is the best solution, if there are some better ones please share them with me